I have issues buying Base Coins. Error: Fail with error 'TransferHelper: TRANSFER_FROM_FAILED'
web3= Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider(alchemy))

#print(web3.is_connected())

#Instancia contrato uniswap
uniswap_router_contract = web3.eth.contract(address=botuni, abi=abiBot)

# Crear instancia del contrato del token
token_contract = web3.eth.contract(address=tokenAddress, abi=abiToken)

# Cantidad de tokens que deseas aprobar (en unidades del token, no en wei)
montoCambiario = web3.to_wei(0.00001, 'ether') 

deadline = int((datetime.now() + timedelta(minutes=10)).timestamp())  # 10 minutos desde ahora

amount_in=web3.to_wei(1, 'ether') #recalcular en weth
amount_out= web3.to_wei(0.9, 'ether')

'''
allowance = token_contract.functions.allowance(metamaskAddress, botuni).call()
print(f"Current allowance for botuni: {allowance}")
'''

#token_contract.functions.approve(botuni, amount_in).transact({'from': metamaskAddress})


# Construir la transacción de aprobación
approve_tx = token_contract.functions.approve(
    #uniswap_router_contract,
    botuni,
    amount_in
).build_transaction({
    'from': metamaskAddress,
    'gas': 2000000,
    'gasPrice': web3.to_wei('0.023511279', 'gwei'),
    'nonce': web3.eth.get_transaction_count(metamaskAddress)
})

# Firmar y enviar la transacción de aprobación
signed_approve_tx = web3.eth.account.sign_transaction(approve_tx, private_key=pk)
approve_tx_hash = web3.eth.send_raw_transaction(signed_approve_tx.rawTransaction)

# Imprimir el hash de la transacción de aprobación
print(f"Approval transaction sent with hash: {approve_tx_hash.hex()}")

# Esperar a que la transacción de aprobación sea minada
web3.eth.wait_for_transaction_receipt(approve_tx_hash)





# Configurar la transacción de intercambio
tx = uniswap_router_contract.functions.swapExactTokensForTokens( 
    amount_in,  # Cantidad de tokens a intercambiar
    amount_out,  # amountOutMin 
    [wethAddress, tokenAddress],      #Path, podemos probar cambiando la weth, token
    metamaskAddress,
    deadline
).build_transaction({
    'from': metamaskAddress,
    'value': montoCambiario,
    'gas': 2000000,
    'gasPrice': web3.to_wei('0.023511279', 'gwei'),
    'nonce': web3.eth.get_transaction_count(metamaskAddress),
    'value' : 0
})

# Firmar la transacción
signed_tx = web3.eth.account.sign_transaction(tx, private_key=pk)

# Enviar la transacción
tx_hash = web3.eth.send_raw_transaction(signed_tx.rawTransaction)

print(f"Transacción enviada. Hash: {tx_hash.hex()}")


# Esperar a que la transacción sea confirmada
tx_receipt = web3.eth.wait_for_transaction_receipt(tx_hash)

print(f"Transacción confirmada. Receipt: {tx_receipt}")

Python using web3py.
Im trying to swap weth for an specific coin on Base but I got an error on BaseScan
Status:
Fail with error 'TransferHelper: TRANSFER_FROM_FAILED'
